# AMD À la carte Extension Methods On Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, js-amd

I am developing a javascript library and would like to store groups of optional methods on a Javascript object in different modules.

The library has two modules, lets call them ModuleA and ModuleB. ModuleA exports a class object, lets call it ClassA, that only has minimal, core functionality. ModuleB defines a set of optional methods to be set on the prototype of ClassA.

In a third module not in the library, ModuleC, I would like the following:

- If I import only ModuleA and instantiate ClassA, I know I have access to all ModuleA methods on InstanceA using 'InstanceA.MethodA(...)'. (Other methods may be defined on InstanceA as well)
- If I import both ModuleA and ModuleB and instantiate ClassA, I know I have access to all ModuleA methods as well as ModuleB methods on InstanceA using 'InstanceA.MethodA(...)' and 'InstanceA.MethodB(...)'.

I have considered a few solutions but am unsure if there is a preferred way to accomplish this. Here is what I have considered:

**ModuleB alters ClassA** The factory for ModuleB import ModuleA and alters ClassA. Would these changes be guaranteed to persist? Does AMD guarantee importing the same module across an environment always returns the same object?

**ModuleB returns altered ClassA** ModuleB extends ClassA and returns new Object. This would probably work fine in this example with only two modules, but what about with multiple optional method modules?

Please let me know if you have encountered a similar situation and what your solution was.

Comment: BTW, both approaches work. However, as far as I can tell, the first approach relies on non-standard behavior. The module loading implementations I have tested keep a cached version of loaded modules. However, the AMD spec does not seem to have anything to say about module definition side effects. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: Dojo AMD Loader [documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd): `define` has two additional important characteristics that may not be immediately obvious:

Comment: 1. Module creation is lazy and asynchronous, and does not occur immediately when `define` is called. This means that factory is not executed, and any dependencies of the module will not be resolved, until some running code actually requires the module.

Comment: 2. Once a module value has been entered into the module namespace, it is not recomputed each time it is demanded. On a practical level, this means that factory is only invoked once, and the returned value is cached and shared among all code that uses a given module. (Note: the dojo loader includes the nonstandard function `require.undef`, which undefines a module value.)

Comment: N.B.: _require.js_ also has `require.undef(mid)`, so that way you can lose a cached version of loaded module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my approach:

```
// Module A - Define ClassA
define(function() {
    function ClassA() {}
    ClassA.prototype.methodA = function() {};
    return ClassA;
});

// Module B - Extend
define(function() {
    return function(ClassToExtend) {
         ClassToExtend.prototype.methodB = function() { };
    };
});

// Module C - Sticking
define(function(require) {

    // Define ClassA
    var ClassA = require("module_a");

    // Extend ClassA with custom methods of ModuleB
    require("module_b")(ClassA);

    // Instanciate extended ClassA
    var InstanceA = new ClassA();
}
```

Comment: I had not really considered this approach, but it looks good and makes the extension more explicit. One extra thing to note, I added checks in ModuleB, the extension module, to make sure I don't overwrite existing properties. Combined with the module loading logic that phusick described, this works pretty well.